# Adding Database in MariaDB on Swisscom Cloud

Tags: mariadb, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

Is it possible to `CREATE DATABASE` in MariaDB on the Swisscom Cloud? I know I can do this on Amazon RDS, but I'm not sure if this is possible on the Swisscom Cloud. If not: it would be an important feature to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry this is not possible. You receive database space on a shared Galera Cluster (MariaDB) where you are granted all privileges in your own database.

> [Galera Cluster](http://galeracluster.com/products/) for MySQL is  a true Multimaster Cluster based on
>   synchronous replication. Galera Cluster is an easy-to-use,
>   high-availability solution, which provides high system uptime, no data
>   loss and scalability for future growth.

```
> SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for 2RQGCnSeAmJTWYwX@%                                                                                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO '2RQGCnSeAmJTWYwX'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '$HASH' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 10 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `CF_32FD02B6_9B18_473D_A4D8_C84E19EC6F2C`.* TO '2RQGCnSeAmJTWYwX'@'%'                                                |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Here the error (Access denied) when creating a new database

```
MariaDB [CF_32FD02B6_9B18_473D_A4D8_C84E19EC6F2C]> create database rokfor;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user '2RQGCnSeAmJTWYwX'@'%' to database 'rokfor'
```

Please subscribe to our newsletter for new feature announcements.

Comment: Thanks - I feared that this would be the case. Would be a nice to have to compete with AWS.

Answer (score 1):

rokfor - would it be possible for you to share a little bit more insights, why you need to create your own database? (behind the scenes on each service creation of a mariadb service, you get your an own database.)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: My use case is this: I developed a headless cms based on php/composer which runs nice in the swisscom cloud or on aws beanstalk. It's a multi customer environment, and each customer has his own database. That makes it easy for me keep track of the customers activities, measure the size of a customer's database for example. Amazon lets me create as many databases I want within one RDB Instance. If I create for every customer a MariaDB service, I will end up with quite a huge bill and many underused services.

Answer (score 1):

@rokfor:
We have some substantial improvements planned in roadmap for MariaDB in Q3/Q4.
The possibility of adding new Schema/DB is not of them ... but we have some other features in the pipeline that I believe will eliminate the whole need for such feature. Can you, please, share with us why would you need such feature to confirm our assumptions? TIA!

Stay up to date with Application Cloud News via newsletter or our news page:
https://developer.swisscom.com/news

Michal Maczka
Product Manager Swisscom Application Cloud

Comment: Refer to my answer above. In the end, it's about money: Running 10 small MariaDB services compared to one MySQL RDB instance on AWS with 10 Databases is much more expensive unless you're using the MariaDB Services up to the limit.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Stay up to date with our news as soon we should have something for!